# Can singular 2-simplices be identified with homotopies?

Tags: algebraic-topology, terminology, intuition, homology-cohomology, simplex

In what follows, let $\sigma_p$ be the standard p-simplex in $\mathbb{R}^{p+1}$. This question is inspired by the following quote from Vick's *Homology Theory*, p.3:

> Let $X$ be a topological space. A singular p-simplex in $X$ is a continuous function $$\phi: \sigma_p \to X.$$ Note that singular 0-simplices may be identified with the points of $X$, the singular 1-simplices with the paths in $X$, **and so forth** [emphasis mine].

This immediately made me wonder if singular 2-simplices may be identified with the homotopies of $X$. Now obviously the standard 2-simplex is homeomorphic to $[0,1]\times[0,1]$, so there exists a continuous map $\psi: [0,1]\times[0,1]\to\sigma_2$, and thus by composition, for any singular 2-simplex $\phi:\sigma_2\to X$, we automatically have a continuous map $\phi\circ\psi:[0,1]\times[0,1]\to X$.

However, in order for this to be a homotopy, we need additionally that the maps $\phi\circ\psi(0,-):[0,1]\to X$ and $\phi\circ\psi(1,-):[0,1]\to X$ be constants (at least according to the definition of homotopy given in Hatcher's *Algebraic Topology*).

**Question:** does there exist such a continuous map $\psi:[0,1]\times[0,1]\to \sigma_2$ which satisfies these two additional conditions?

**EDIT:** [This page](http://planning.cs.uiuc.edu/node275.html) claims that we can replace continuous maps from the standard $k-$simplex with continuous maps from the closed $k-$ball, although it makes the mistake of saying that $\phi$ has to be a homeomorphism (it just has to be continuous), and it doesn't mention $[0,1]^k$ ($k-$cubes) at all, which would be necessary to define a $k-$homotopy.

[This page](https://books.google.de/books?id=YkyizIcJdK0C&pg=PA105&lpg=PA105&dq=singular%20simplex&source=bl&ots=hAOQNWAsFM&sig=P_fntSM7G6tzqQ9ewbx0C4QsLDU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi_geq2rJfQAhUB1RQKHVvyB8MQ6AEIUzAI#v=onepage&q=singular%20simplex&f=false) also states the claim that singular 1-simplices can be identified with paths, and it says that

> We could generalize the fundamental group by taking homotopy classes of singular $n-$simplices in $X$, and making an appropriate definition of the 'product' of two singular simplicies. This can indeed be done, but the resulting groups are the homotopy groups $\pi_n(X)$.

This would seem to corroborate my suspicion that singular $2-$simplices are either related or equivalent to the set of all path homotopies in $X$, but I am not really sure.

[This webpage](http://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Singular_simplex) claims that singular 0-simplices can be identified with points, and that singular 1-simplices can be identified with paths, but it says "Fill this in later" for singular 2-simplices.

[This webpage](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/singular+simplicial+complex) states that singular $n-$simplices generalize paths in $X$, but it doesn't clarify how, specifically whether this generalization is the same as homotopies. Although it does say that "this construction... is one of the classical approaches to determining invariants of the homotopy type of the space". And it says that the singular simplicial complex of $X$ is its [nerve](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/nerve).

[This document](http://math.ucr.edu/home/baez/homotopy/homotopy.pdf) gives a nice intuition of how in other contexts homotopies are a natural generalization of points and paths to higher dimensions.

Comment: A 2-simplex is a homotopy between a path and the concatenation of two other paths (the faces of the simplex).

Comment: @NajibIdrissi So can singular 2-simplices be identified with the homotopies of $X$, and singular n-simplices identified with the n-homotopies of $X$?

Comment: The natural way to deal with homotopies is cubically - see some comments on this on https://arxiv.org/abs/1610.07421 "Modelling and Computing Homotopy Types:I". The reason is the rule $I^m \times I^n \cong I^{m+n}$. Compare the book by Massey on "Singular Homology".

Comment: For future reference: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/2009130/327486

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(Speaking as someone who hasn't really had time to digest all of this stuff)

Let $I$ be the interval and assume that we are working in a cartesian closed subcategory of **Top**. (this assumption can be removed if needed, by taking these arguments as merely inspiration and only using the function-space-free statements they inspire)

The intuition about a homotopy is to view them not as maps $I \times X \to Y$, but as maps $I \to Y^X$: a homotopy between two functions is just a path in the corresponding function space.

To any space $X$, the homotopies in $X$ are the maps $I \to X$, and we can collect them into a space $X^I$. For any particular points $a,b \in X$, we can also consider paths between them:

$$ \text{Path}(a,b) = \{ f \in X^I | f(0) = a \wedge f(1) = b \} $$

Now, if we are to speak of a homotopy of homotopies, we might thus consider maps $I \to X^I$. These are (I think) called "free" homotopies. Of course, these correspond to maps $I^2 \to X$.

But to any points $a,b \in X$, we may also consider maps $I \to \text{Path(a,b)}$ — *this* is what is usually meant when one speaks of a "homotopy between paths". These correspond precisely to those maps $I^2 \to X$ whose left and right sides are the constant functions to $a$ and $b$.

Since we insist on the two sides being constant functions, we might as well work in the quotient space that collapses each side to a point. The end result is still homeomorphic to $I^2$, but the result is maybe easier to express by constructing a homeomorphism to $D^2$ (the unit disc) instead.

There are lots of spaces homeomorphic to $D^2$ that we could use. Each gives different flavor.

The unit disc $D^2$ emphasizes the nature of a homotopy as being from one path to another; more generally the $n$-globe (i.e. unit $n$-ball) $D^n$ can be viewed as a generalized path from its upper and lower hemispheres, which are copies of $D^{n-1}$.

The simplices $\Delta^n$ better emphasize composition; e.g. $\Delta^2$ can be viewed as relating a composite of two paths to a third path. $\Delta^3$ gives a sort of ternary composition of a triangle being subdivided by adding a new point in its middle. These are historically important as their combinatorial theory (simplicial sets) was worked out first, and is maybe simpler to calculuate with?

The cubes $I^n$ arise naturally from the sort of reasoning I give above, and allow for the obvious binary compositions along all of their axes. As for regarding $I^2$ as a path between paths, I think the better picture is not to think of it as going from the South edge to the North edge, but as a path between composites $\text{South}\cdot\text{East} \to \text{West}\cdot\text{North}$.

Other shapes could be used, of course; but these shapes are the most popular and studied the most, and the corresponding combinatorial versions have names: "globular sets", simplicial sets", and "cubical sets".

Comment: This is a great answer, especially since it read my mind and also addressed my confusion about why simplices are used instead of cubes or closed spheres or any other compact convex body. Before I accept it, I just want to double-check: if I wrote down in my notes that "the singular 2-simplices can be identified with the homotopies in $X$" and "the singular n-simplices can be identified with the n-homotopies in $X$", would I be misleading myself/writing down something wrong? I really want to, because I feel like understanding the chain group as the free abelianization of the same types of

Comment: objects from homotopy theory would allow me to apply whatever intuition I have about homotopies to homology theory, because right now I am having difficulty understanding how homology is supposed to be related to other areas of math (since the only definition that seems to use the simplex aspect of the definition very much is the boundary operator, but seemingly one should be able to modify the definition of the boundary operator to work for spaces homeomorphic to the simplex, otherwise singular homology wouldn't seem like a good way to find topological invariants). Besides discussing the

Comment: singular 0- or 1-simplices in $X$, no text I could find seems to go into length about how to interpret singular n-simplices before taking their free abelianization and quotienting it out of the blue. I know Hatcher's prelude to chapter 2 about homology is supposed to hint at this, but it isn't really entirely clear to me exactly what he is getting at in that section. But anyway,  I know that there are people who study cubical complexes instead of simplicial complexes, and CW complexes are almost "generalized spherical complexes", and those two spaces are used to characterize homotopies, so

Comment: the absence of spheres and cubes in singular homology theory and the sudden appearance of simplices just comes somewhat as a surprise and makes it more difficult for me to develop intuition about chains. So anyway, knowing whether or not I could safely write down in my notes "singular n-simplices can be identified with the n-homotopies in X" would either way really improve my understanding of the subject at a conceptual level.

Comment: @William: It sounds reasonable to me (but to disclaim again, I'm not really an expert!). One aspect of all this that I haven't really digested is that all of these spaces are homotopic to a point anyways, so from the point of homotopy theory they're all telling us the 'same' thing -- the actual content is in the relationships between them.